# How do I go to a specific folder/drive in the shell on Ubuntu on Windows?

Tags: command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to contribute in open projects . But the procedure given for installing the projects in local machine is for Ubuntu and I am using Windows.

Also I tried Ubuntu shell  But in that I could not understand how to go to a specific folder (specific drive).

How can I do that?

Comment: If you are trying to install projects aimed at Ubuntu, the easiest and best option is to use Ubuntu. If you don't want to install it, you can run it inside a Virtualbox that runs in your Windows OS.

Answer (score 1):

You can run Linux commands in one of three ways from the Windows Command Prompt, that I can think of off the top of my head:

**1. [GNU for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/)** - a bundle of common GNU commands compiled specifically to run under Windows operating environment. Out of date, but a valid answer. May be useful to also get [CoreUtils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) for Windows - I’m not sure how much overlap exists between these two solutions.

**2. [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/)** -  a more comprehensive set of Linux command-line utilities/applications/etc., compiled to run (with a dedicated cygwin DLL) natively under Windows.

**3. [Bash on Windows 10](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about)** - And, if you’ve got Windows 10, you can run Ubuntu Linux natively in Windows, with almost the entirety of the distribution available, by enabling the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) feature.

Comment: haha, WSL has *almost the entirety of the distribution available*, +1 just for that!